# Facebook OpenGraph API: How do I retrieve a list of all crossposts that use my video?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-insights, cross-posting

My ultimate goal is to retrieve a list of all crossposts of a video, each with the number of views that occurred on that specific post. This information is available in the video modal in Business Manager, but I need to get the breakdown in an automated fashion.

Comment: Sharing a video post, and crossposting a video are two different things AFAIK. `/[video-id]/sharedposts` would only get you shared posts - and if it is user profiles sharing the post, then you will only get it if the user granted your app permission to read their posts.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I've actually been working on getting sharedposts and crossposts and seem to have accidentally conflated them in my question. I'll update it accordingly.